# Jqgrid advanced searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using a jqgrid grid that displays results when a search button is clicked.  I am also using the advanced search button to filter the data.

Here is the problem: if the user filters the data by using an advanced search, and then tries to search again, the jqgrid still sends in `_search=true`. The only way that I know is to click the Reload grid button or to click the reset button from the advanced search. Is there a way to reset `_search=false` without having to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

```
    $('#gridname').setGridParam(
    {
         search: false,
         ...
    }
```

when you do a search so that jqgrid reset the _search parameter